# Import Error after upgrade python 2.6 to 2.7

Tags: python, tweepy

I got a problem to install tweepy on a Linux server as the error below:

```
[kapom@neptune tweepy-dir]$ sudo python setup.py install    
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "setup.py", line 3, in <module>
        from setuptools import setup, find_packages
    ImportError: No module named setuptools
```

Then I try to install a package setuptools.. but got another error like this...

```
[kapom@neptune setuptools-0.9.8]$ sudo python setup.py install --prefix=/opt/setuptools
running install
Checking .pth file support in /opt/setuptools/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
/usr/bin/python -E -c pass
TEST FAILED: /opt/setuptools/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ does NOT support .pth files
error: bad install directory or PYTHONPATH

You are attempting to install a package to a directory that is not
on PYTHONPATH and which Python does not read ".pth" files from.  The
installation directory you specified (via --install-dir, --prefix, or
the distutils default setting) was:

    /opt/setuptools/lib/python2.7/site-packages/

and your PYTHONPATH environment variable currently contains:

    ''

Here are some of your options for correcting the problem:

* You can choose a different installation directory, i.e., one that is
  on PYTHONPATH or supports .pth files

* You can add the installation directory to the PYTHONPATH environment
  variable.  (It must then also be on PYTHONPATH whenever you run
  Python and want to use the package(s) you are installing.)

* You can set up the installation directory to support ".pth" files by
  using one of the approaches described here:

  https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/easy_install.html#custom-installation-locations

Please make the appropriate changes for your system and try again.
```

I'm not sure what I did wrong. Anyone please help me :(

**Note****
Before try to install the tweepy I updated the python version from 2.6 to 2.7 as command below..

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python2.7 /usr/bin/python2.7 10
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why didn't you use the [setuptools installation instructions](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools/0.9.8#installation-instructions)? I doubt `setuptools` supports a prefix option; use the `python` binary into which you want to install `setuptools` and omit the `prefix`.

Comment: I'm thinking it really causes of the steps of install setuptools or not... because I'm trying to import another pack but also cannot
`[kapom@neptune site-packages]$ python
Python 2.7.2 (default, Aug  1 2013, 16:31:44)
[GCC 4.4.6 20120305 (Red Hat 4.4.6-4)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import date
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named date
>>>
`

Comment: The other package *requires* `setuptools` to be installed first. But the way you install `setuptools` is.. odd.

Comment: There is no module named `date` in the Python standard library. At all. Not in Python 2.6 or 2.7.

Comment: Ah...Thank you Martijin. Last night, I set a PYTHONPATH to new directory and it worked properly, not sure the root cause, but good to continue working haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep your script and clean install python 2.7 after uninstalling what you currently have, there are some issues when upgrading or having multiple py 2.x/3.x install's

Comment: @user2641609 yes, uninstall any and all python stuff, and clean install 2.7